# Can i use the following code or it's incorrect?

Tags: c, string, char, character

Well first i'm using language c i still a beginner.

```
char S[20];
S ="ewer" ;
```

is that correct.

Comment: Nope - time to get a [good C book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start studying...

Comment: explain why it won't work ?

Comment: See [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861294/can-i-use-the-following-code-or-its-incorrect/30861356#30861356)...

Comment: Please read difference between "arrays" and "pointers". You can do "assignment","increment" etc for a pointer but not for an array

Answer (score 1):

Arrays (including strings) can't be assigned in C. For strings you need [strcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy), or preferably [strncpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy):

```
#include <string.h>

...

char S[20];

strcpy(S, "ewer");             // strcpy is fine for this example

strncpy(S, "ewer", sizeof(S)); // strncpy is safer in general and
                               // should be preferred over strcpy
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that won't work.

The variable `S` is an array, and you can't assign to arrays like that in C. The string `"ewer"` is represented as an array of characters terminated by the character `'\0'`. To copy it into the array, you need to use a function:

```
strcpy(S, "ewer");
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question. In fact, if you'd wrote `char* S` instead, the example would worked. You might be confused by the fact, that arrays and pointers have many alike things — like `[]` operator.

But you must understand that array is different from a pointer. One of the main differences is that you couldn't increment an array, like `++myArr` *(this code okay for pointer, but not for an array)*. The other one you see in the question: you can not reassign an array variable to point another array. That is exactly what you're trying to do: you're assigning to the array variable `S` a pointer to a place with the text `"ewer"`, that won't work.

Assuming that you wanted to assign to an array the text, you could do the following:

```
char S[] = "ewer";
```

Here you say to the compiler to allocate as much space on the stack, as the `"ewer"` text *(plus the zero end character)* holds, and copy that text there. Notice the empty braces `[]` — you don't even need to manually count symbols, it would be done for you by a compiler.

Comment: Forgot to add: to find the size of `S` that was declared with empty braces, you have to apply `sizeof()`, like `sizeof(S)`.